# Is Luong Yen bus station still operational?

Tags: buses, vietnam, hanoi

I am trying to take a bus from Luong Yen bus station in Hanoi (to Cat Ba island), and some Vietnamese news web sites mention that the bus station is no longer operational. However, a travel agent today said me that I can still take a bus from there, so I'm trying to figure out which source is correct.

It is 11pm right now here in Hanoi, and I would rather prefer to know this online instead of waking up someone in the middle of the night (to take bus tomorrow morning).

The Vietnamese news web site was updated May this year, and Wikitravel was updated at around same days. Has anyone taken a bus from Hanoi to Cat Ba island from the Luong Yen bus station in past 1-2 months?

Here is a news item about the bus station closing down: http://en.vietnamplus.vn/hanoi-to-close-luong-yen-bus-station/94051.vnp

The reason why I'm a bit skeptic about this is that the person who recommended me this bus works in a travel agency and he sounded he knew his job, hence asking the help from the inter webs.

Comment: Care to share your sources (i.e. the links)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cat_Ba) has:

> Luong Yen Bus Station is closed since the beginning of August 2016. The Hoang Long Bus Company now leaves from another bus station, ca. 10 km south of the old quarter. The name of the bus station is Bến xe Nước ngầm (Ngọc Hồi, Hoàng Liệt, Hoàng Mai, Hà Nội).

Comment: Here's an original source (Vietnamese, but Google gives the gist) for the bus station move: http://hoanglong.asia/tin-tuc-hoang-long-asia/thong-bao-chinh-thuc-ve-ben-xe-nuoc-ngam-157.html

Comment: Thank you! You (and Wikitravel) are right. I called the Hoang Long bus company, and they confirmed the new location. I could catch the bus from near the bridge in Red river, but the buses from this company always depart from this location.